# How do we manage transactional IDs on an application running multiple processes in Kafka Confluent Golang?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

Overview of the application:
An ingestion service which accepts logs from clients. The logs are processed and are then pushed into Kafka. Since these logs are critical and I cannot afford a loss in the same, I decided to adopt transactions for the same.

The docs state:

> A producer instance is configured for transactions by setting the
> transactional.id to an identifier unique for the application. This id
> will be used to fence stale transactions from previous instances of the application, typically > following an outage or crash.

I'm generating a static transaction ID at the start of the application. This will imply that on multiple calls to the API (at the same time for different processes) the same transaction ID will be used. Won't this lead to multiple processes producing data sequentially?

Is this the correct way of doing this? And if not, how do I improve this?

Answer (score 1):

With idempotency and transactions in Kafka, you can have the *exactly-once* guarantee in Kafka. But it seems that you need the *at-least-once* guarantee instead. It guarantees that a log message is never lost, but may be duplicated.

In order to turn on this guarantee, you need to, in your *producer*, set [`acks=all`](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#acks). Whenever you produce something to kafka, no data is lost as long as *one in-sync replica* is alive.

I have worked with critical logs before, and Kafka, with `acks=all` set, was never the problem. Data was lost in the producer, before ever entering Kafka's domain.

Maybe I misunderstood your question, let me know if that's the case.